# Generic Docker image with multiple containers passing docker-compose variables

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, containers, environment

I am currently building an angular application that will be made into a docker image. After making this image, it should be usable for several people.

The problem is that I am unable to pass variables from docker-compose to the angular application.

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  dashboard:
    image: imagename
    build:
      context: .
    ports: ["4200:8080"]
    volumes: ["./dev/config.json:/usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/assets/config/conf.json"]
    environment:
      - KEY=EnvToBePassed
```

Comment: What sort of variable are you trying to set?  How is it accessed from the code?  How can you tell it's not being passed along?

Comment: I am trying to send the env variable from docker-compose into the container. Like the apiUrl. I am trying to do it with envsubst but it's not working for now.

Comment: Please edit the question to include these details.  For example, how and where are you calling `envsubst`, and when you say "it's not working", what result do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Create assets/env.js

```
(function(window) {
  window["env"] = window["env"] || {};

  // Environment variables
  window["env"]["apiUrl"] = "../assets/lorem.json";
  window["env"]["CompanyName"] = "Company name";
})(this);
```

create assets/env.template.js

```
(function(window) {
  window["env"] = window["env"] || {};

  // Environment variables
  window["env"]["apiUrl"] = "../assets/lorem.json";
  window["env"]["CompanyName"] = "Company name";
})(this);
```

Call it in the Dockerfile

```
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

Environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: "../assets/lorem.json",
  CompanyName: "Company name"
};
```

Environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
// @ts-ignore
  apiUrl: window["env"]["apiUrl"] || "../assets/lorem.json",
// @ts-ignore
  CompanyName: window["env"]["CompanyName"] || "Company name"
};
```

Call it from the index.html

```
<script src="./assets/env.js"></script>
```